# Weird Google result description

Tags: support, hot-questions, google

The thread in question:

[Matlab: Scatter plots with large datasets & colorbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074686/matlab-scatter-plots-with-large-datasets-colorbar)

Screenshot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Google query was "matlab plot penis".

Comment: Seems like this question happened to be in the Hot Network Questions list (maybe from biology.SE?) when google indexed the page...

Comment: Why were you searching for "matlab plot penis"  anyways???

Comment: ...to plot a penis in matlab. do you happen to know how?

Comment: ........ ***headdesk***

Comment: [This is for a TI, but the basic principal is the same](http://graphadick.blogspot.com/2009/08/instructions.html)

Comment: This post may just join teh other epics on the network, given time! Perfect setting - OP wanting to look for something as innocent as plotting a penis with matlab (creativity points right there) - and Google using its algorithm to escalate it quickly!

Comment: laugh tears in my eyes / makes it harder for me to / upvote all the things

Comment: @JanDvorak To make a plot [with knobs on](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/with+knobs+on)?

Comment: This post will go down in history as the craziest one so far.

Comment: What **did** happen to Thalia's truck anyway?

Comment: Hot tip! Googling "what happens to Thalia's truck" has this thread at number 5! Anyway, I think [this is what happened to Talia's truck](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67527/what-happens-to-talias-truck-driver-in-batman-the-dark-knight-rises). Not quite sure how Batman is related to Matlab and penis plots...

Comment: _contemplates which SE site would be best to ask "How do I graph a penis in matlab"_

Comment: it should be drawn vs time

Comment: Very funny, but sometimes other questions listed on a page <s>dic</s> … messes up googling by creating useless hits for a query.

Comment: Now all we need is a Stack Overflow question on this :D

Comment: I have to say I am offended by such words in that image. How can this allowed on here? I am so disappointed.

Comment: `y = cos(x) + cos(2x)` polar for `x` in 0...2π.

Comment: **PEN!S** Oh my god...

Answer (score 112, accepted):

[This question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21207/why-doesnt-water-enter-my-body-through-my-anus-or-genitals-when-swimming) was shown in the "hot network questions" list:

It used to have a slightly less mature title (involving buttholes instead of anuses) which is why you got that title in your search results.

Comment: Damn, this is good for a laugh.

Comment: Next Question: Weird Google result description at 'meta.stackoverflow.com'

Comment: So is it reasonable to suggest that search accuracy would be improved if stackexchange would omit that "hot questions" sidebar when serving pages to Googlebot?

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley That is a very good point. If there's not already a bug report about that, there probably should be.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you figure this out?

Comment: Admit it, you just want me to admit that I googled for something involving buttholes and/or dicks! ;) https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+exchange+water+butt+hole

Answer (score 42):

Google's algorithm is smart enough to figure out that references to MatLab's phallic plotting capabilities is actually a secret virtual handshake. Thus it tries to return an equally interesting result - amusing to the common eye, but an answer in a nutshell to whoever is calling out.

The real question, if you ask me, is what happens to Thalia's truck?

Comment: I'm dying to know that.

Comment: @RafaelEyng https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/67527