# Related questions sidebar titles inappropriately indexed by search engines

Tags: bug, search, related-questions

Searches in external general-purpose web search engine (i.e. google) find stack overflow question pages that only partially apply, because there happens to be matches not in the text of the question and answers, but in the sidebar of related questions from when the page was last indexed.

My example, searched for 'uitextfield "placeholder" minimumFontSize' which relates to `uitextfield` and `minimumFontSize` but not at all `placeholder`, except that a related question is titled "iPhone UITextField - Change placeholder text color".

I believe this to be a bug. In principle, the similar & trending questions sidebar is not part of a questions's content, its rather a navigation aid for when the page is viewed by humans. The google spider does not benefit from that sidebar. In practice, this causes search engines to show many false positive hits. When refining searches, it can be so distracting to mentally filter out those false positives that I often give up and have the search engine automatically filter out *all* of stackoverflow!

Can something be done about this?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286485/stack-overflow-search-returns-no-results-but-google-search-returns-2-000/286487#286487 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271848/weird-google-result-description

Comment: I find the accepted answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286589/592739 to the former link to be a satisfactory answer to my questions too. If someone can mark my question as a duplicate of that, please do