# Google result shows title: "Not the answer you're looking for? Browse..." for SO question link

Tags: bug, seo

I just googled [spring boot test redirect](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=spring%20boot%20test%20redirect) and the first result, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142871/test-http-status-code-of-redirected-url-with-mockmvc) with the title

> Test HTTP status code of redirected URL with MockMvc

appears like this in the result page

[image]

The SO result appears with the title:

> Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged...

which is the usual `<h2>` element content at the bottom of the page.

Comment: [Could be worse.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271848/weird-google-result-description)

Comment: @PaulCrovella that guy was onto something...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245666/google-search-showing-not-the-answer-youre-looking-for-browse-other-questions

Comment: @PaulCrovella awesome...

Comment: *Was* it the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I am so disappointed that the question causing this wasn't about Android...

Answer (score 21):

Most likely this is due to SO abusing the `<h2>` tag to display

> ### Not the answer you're looking for? Browse other questions tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) [spring-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) [spring-boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-boot) [mockmvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mockmvc) [spring-mvc-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc-test) or [ask your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

This makes Google believe that it is an actual section title on the page, and that title nicely matches your search criteria (“*spring boot test redirect*” – 3 out of 4 words) because it contains the question tags.

If you [search for the question title](https://www.google.com/search?q=Test%20HTTP%20status%20code%20of%20redirected%20URL%20with%20MockMvc&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), the search results show it properly with the exact same link:

[image: Google search with exact title]

Comment: Nice description of problem's origin. But not always someone knows *exact title* of question he is looking for. And this is sad.

Comment: @Dima This was just to show that Google adapts the link titles based on your search criteria, it's not supposed to represent an actual search 

Comment: Oh, Didier L, yes, I got it when I've read your answer. And my comment wasn't about criticize your answer. Probably I had to insert some brackets in my first comment to empasize it))

Comment: Ehm, the sentence _is_ an actual section title on the page.